# Swift 2.0 Print function

Tags: ios

What is the difference between `NSLog()`, `println`, and `print`?

From my experience and understanding, they all write in the Console/Debugging area but why is there the change in Swift v1.2 and v2.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use 2.0 then `print` will offer more functionality, but they are still the same thing. Please refer to the documentation to see the added functionality.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/

Also don't use NSLog if you are using Swift

Comment: There are valid reasons to use NSLog in Swift, like when your output shall appear on the system console in production or when thread synchrony is required.